# Script to delete old files and leave the newest one in a directory in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rm

I have a backup tool that takes database backup daily and stores them with the following format:

```
*_DATE_*.*.sql.gz
```

with `DATE` being in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

How could I delete old files (by comparing `YYYY-MM-DD` in the filenames) matching the pattern above, while leaving only the newest one.

Example:

```
wordpress_2020-01-27_06h25m.Monday.sql.gz
wordpress_2020-01-28_06h25m.Tuesday.sql.gz
wordpress_2020-01-29_06h25m.Wednesday.sql.gz
```

Ath the end only the last file, meaning `wordpress_2020-01-29_06h25m.Wednesday.sql.gz` should remain.

Comment: Have you considered deleting them based on their creation date or last modification date rather than their file name? This would be made easier by tools such as `find` which have native capabilities to select files based on these dates. Of course this might not be reliable in your context

Comment: @senheisen : You did not describe, how the part of the filename _before_ the `DATE` part looks like, but assuming that there are no arbitrary underscores in that, you could pipe the `*.sql.gz` list of the files into `sort ....`, specify the underscore as field separator, and sort ascending descending to the second field.  The first entry in the sorted list is the one to keep, the remaining ones are those to delete.

Comment: @user1934428 for example: `wordpress_2020-01-29_06h25m.Wednesday.sql.gz`

Comment: @Aaron the backup tool generates the files with date in their names, thought it might be easier to handle with filenames instead of querying the file dates.

Comment: @senheisen : If they all look as simple as this, you could go ahead with my proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- The preceding substring left to `_DATE_` portion does not contain underscores.
- The filenames do not contain newline characters.

Then would you try the following:

```
for f in *.sql.gz; do
    echo "$f"
done | sort -t "_" -k 2 | head -n -1 | xargs rm --
```

If your `head` and `cut` commands support `-z` option, following code will be more robust against special characters in the filenames:

```
for f in *.sql.gz; do
    [[ $f =~ _([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2})_ ]] && \
        printf "%s\t%s\0" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$f"
done | sort -z | head -z -n -1 | cut -z -f 2- | xargs -0 rm --
```

- It makes use of the `NUL` character as a line delimiter and allows any special characters in the filenames.
- It first extracts the `DATE` portion from the filename, then prepend it to the filename as a first field separated by a tab character.
- Then it sorts the files with the `DATE` string, exclude the last (newest) one, then retrieve the filename cutting the first field off, then remove those files.

Comment: Can i add that regex in my post? Nice I'm not good at it and that is the missing puzzle in my post :-).

Comment: @Jetchisel Sure. My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the folder where you have `*_DATE_*.*.sql.gz` files and try below command

```
ls -ltr *.sql.gz|awk '{print $9}'|awk '/2020/{print $0}' |xargs rm
```

or

use

```
`ls -ltr |grep '2019-05-20'|awk '{print $9}'|xargs rm`
```

replace`/2020/` with the pattern you want to delete. example `2020-05-01` replace as `/2020-05-01/`

Comment: Note that this doesn't use the stated requirement *by comparing YYYY-MM-DD in the filenames*. It may be a valid approach, but worth highlighting the above

Comment: Why not just `ls -tr *_DATE_*.sq.gz | sed '1d' | xargs rm`?

Comment: @daniu he want to delete files that match his specific date

Comment: @DevOpsGeek not a specific date, but a specific date format.

Comment: @senheisen replace /2020/ with your format and delete them

Comment: @DevOpsGeek `rm: missing operand`

Comment: @DevOpsGeek `root@ubunt:/tmp# ls -ltr *.sql.gz|awk '{print $9}'|awk 'YYYY-MM-DD{print $0}' |xargs rm
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.`

Comment: [Why you should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: breaks if there are file/path name with spaces and newlines...

Comment: give your YYY-MM-DD in between // like /YYY-MM-DD/

Comment: For example you want to delete `wordpress_2020-01-28_06h25m.Tuesday.sql.gz`  and all files have `2020-01-28` so use below command

`ls -ltr *.sql.gz|awk '{print $9}'|awk '/2020-01-28/{print $0}' |xargs rm`

Comment: Alternately you can you this as well

`ls -ltr |grep '2019-05-20'|awk '{print $9}'|xargs rm`

Answer (score 0):

Since the pattern (glob) you present us is very generic, we have to make an assumption here.

> **assumption:** the date pattern, is the first sequence that matches the regex `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

**Files are of the form: `constant_string_<DATE>_*.sql.gz`**

```
a=( *.sql.gz )
unset a[${#a[@]}-1]
rm "${a[@]}"
```

**Files are of the form: `*_<DATE>_*.sql.gz`**

Using this, it is easily done in the following way:

```
a=( *.sql.gz );
cnt=0; ref="0000-00-00"; for f in "${a[@]}"; do 
   [[ "$f" =~ [0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ]] \
   && [[ "$BASH_REMATCH" > "$ref" ]]    \
   && ref="${BASH_REMATCH}" && refi=$cnt
   ((++cnt))
done
unset a[cnt]
rm "${a[@]}"
```

---

> **`[[ expression ]]`** <snip> 
> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the same precedence as `==` and `!=`.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended  regular  expression and matched  accordingly (as  in  regex(3)). The return value is `0` if the string matches the pattern, and `1` otherwise.  If the regular expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression's return value is `2`.  If the shell option `nocasematch` is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  Any part of the pattern may be  quoted to  force it to be matched as a string.  **Substrings  matched by parenthesized subexpressions within the regular expression are saved in the array variable `BASH_REMATCH`.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index `0` is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index `n` is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression**
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

Comment: BASH_REMATCH worth an explanation ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew added the details.

Comment: @kvantour `$ref` should be the latest file with the latest date. It's not static.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in another question. Although it serves the purpose, but it does not handle the files based on their filenames.

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob  ##: This might not be needed but just in case
                   ##: If there are no files the glob will not expand
latest=
allfiles=()
unwantedfiles=()

for file in *_????-??-??_*.sql.gz; do
  if [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2})_ ]]; then
    allfiles+=("$file")
    [[ $file > $latest ]] && latest=$file  ##: The > is magical inside [[
  fi
done

n=${#allfiles[@]}

if ((n <= 1)); then  ##: No files or only one file don't remove it!!
  printf '%s\n' "Found ${n:-0} ${allfiles[@]:-*sql.gz} file, bye!"
  exit 0    ##: Exit gracefully instead
fi

for f in "${allfiles[@]}"; do
  [[ $latest == $f ]] && continue  ##: Skip the latest file in the loop.
  unwantedfiles+=("$f")  ##: Save all files in an array without the latest.
done

printf 'Deleting the following files: %s\n' "${unwantedfiles[*]}"

echo rm -rf "${unwantedfiles[@]}"
```

Relies heavily on the `>` test operator inside `[[`

You can create a new file with lower dates and should still be good.

The echo is there just to see what's going to happen. Remove it if you're satisfied with the output.

I'm actually using this script via cron now, except for the `*.sql.gz` part since I only have directories to match but the same date formant so I have, `????-??-??/` and only `([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2})` as the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Python script "rotate-archives" for smart delete backups. (https://gitlab.com/k11a/rotate-archives).

An example of starting archives deletion:

```
rotate-archives.py test_mode=off age_from-period-amount_for_last_timeslot=7-5,31-14,365-180-5 archives_dir=/mnt/archives
```

As a result, there will remain archives from 7 to 30 days old with a time interval between archives of 5 days, from 31 to 364 days old with time interval between archives 14 days, from 365 days old with time interval between archives 180 days and the number of 5.

But require move `_date_` to beginning file name or script add current date for new files.